# Set color fill from a field containing RGB values with QGIS 3.22

Tags: qgis-3, symbology

I am using QGIS 3.22 on Ubuntu 22.04.  I have the global ecoregions shapefile available from https://storage.googleapis.com/teow2016/Ecoregions2017.zip.  This has a field called **color**.  The values are RGB values as 6-digit hex, in text format.  How can  I set the polygon colors to the values in this field?  I know this has been asked before for earlier versions of QGIS, but I cannot find an answer that matches the menus on QGIS 3.22.  The screenshot below shows where I have got to, but after numerous efforts, including looking at answers on old versions, I have not been able to see how to do this.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with **Single Symbol**. In the **Fill color** setting click in the [image: 1] icon, then click **Edit** in option of the popup and finally just set the field in the expression editor.

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks Mayo, much appreciated!